# Laravel | Id generada automaticamente

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy haciendo un sistema de noticias y quiero mi url de la siguiente manera:

```
http://web.com/noticias/{id_generado}/
```

El `{id_generado}` es un id que yo genero mediante la función `str_random(10)`.

El problema del asunto es: ¿Qué pasa si dos noticias por casualidad generan el mismo `{id_generado}`?

¿Cómo hago para comprobar antes si ese id ya ha sido asignada a otra noticia y generar una nueva? ¿Con un do-while?

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar una validación antes de guardar
[Manually Creating Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(['id_generado' => 165654165765456], [
        'id_generado' => 'required|unique:noticias|max:255'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // Si falla la validacion ...
    }

    // Si no falla registras en la base ...
}
```

Comment: No me vale eso..., necesito guardar la noticia SIEMPRE, pero con un id unico. Se me ha ocurrido un do-while.

Comment: Yo uso este paquete para esos casos. Nunca se va a repetir un id.  
[integer-hashids](https://github.com/amamarul/integer-hashids)  
Podés también generar hashes alfanumericos solamente utilizando letras en la configuración de la conexion y definir el tamaño de caracteres que quieras

Answer (score 0):

Estaría bien usar el do-while, una de las formas de aplicarlo sería obteniendo todos los ids actuales (un solo query) y comparándolos con el generado:

```
$idsActuales = Noticia::pluck('id_generado');

do {
    $idNuevo = str_random(10);
} while (in_array($idNuevo, $idsActuales));

// guardar noticia con nuevo id
Noticia::create(['id_generado' => $idNuevo]);
```

Comment: ¿No hace falta el metodo all(); de esta manera? Noticia::pluck('id_generado')->all();

Comment: No, no hace falta, pluck existe tanto en el Query Builder de Eloquent como en las colecciones, en el primer caso utiliza las colecciones base. Te invito a probarlo y a revisar su código.